# DB2 ODBC connection doesn't work on R 4.2

Tags: r, db2, odbc, dbi

I had a working connection to a DB2 server from R. Then I ungraded to R v4.2 and it no longer works.

This is my connection string:

```
con_DB2 = DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                         Driver = "IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - C_PROGRA~2_IBM_V111~1.4FP_CLIDRI~1",
                         Database='DB2Q',
                         Hostname='usddcs',
                         Port=3700,
                         PROTOCOL='TCPIP',
                         UID= rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database username"),
                         PWD=rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"))
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: IM004: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed
```

This seems to have been raised in this issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/10509

It was NOT solved, but suggestions are that the encoding might be impacting this. Are there any arguments to the `dbConnect()` function that can be changed to fiddle with encoding to make it work in the new R version?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me with  R4.2.2 on Win10 pro(19045) and Rstudio 2022.07.02-576 and
IBM clidriver version 11.5.6.0 (or higher). It may also work with older driver versions.

The key detail is that you need to have the system environment variable `DB2CODEPAGE=1208` set before starting Rstudio. This tells the clidriver to use utf-8 as the application code page.

If you only want the change to impact Rstudio and R (but not separate command-line based programs, for perl, python, php, clp etc ) then set that variable in the Rstudio script via `Sys.setenv(DB2CODEPAGE=1208)` or equivalent configuration/startup file.

Note that if you are not using clidriver, and instead you are using a larger footprint Db2 client (for example, the fat client, or the runtime client) then you may also use the `db2set DB2CODEPAGE=1208` method of setting the variable, and the consequence should be the same.

Then the database connection to Db2-LUW succeeds (the target database is also utf-8 encoded).

You can also ignore the cli driver and instead try accessing the database via rJDBC and a jdbc driver (there is no shared code between the jdbc driver and the cli driver).

Comment: I simply just added a line of code `Sys.setenv(DB2CODEPAGE=1208)` before the connection string and that did the trick! Thanks!!